# Hide/Show Shortcut For Panel Containing Collections/Properties

Tags: interface

Is there a shortcut or workaround to quickly hide/show the right panel in Blender 2.8? I know it's possible to drag in and out with the mouse but this is not quick, I'm looking for a fast way because sometimes I need to do this many times every few seconds.

[image]

Comment: A work around could be to toggle in and out of Full screen mode. With Blender 2.8 default settings and  mouse hovering over the 3D viewport the keyboard short cut for that is Ctrl + Spacebar.

Comment: If you use this as an answer I will up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

You can maximize the main panel instead (ctrl+spacebar) or toggle it to full screen (ctrl+alt+space)

Comment: This should definitely be the right answer if you're using video editing and want to fiddle with cuttin'n'pasting and just arranging pieces. It's sooo natural to just show the side panels when you need them and to hide them when they are in the way. Great answer @Pavel Trusov!